Not able to unzip a file using Azure Data Factory
My zip folder is of below structure


I have placed this zip file in the ADLS folder.

I have built a copy activity by referring to the documentation and also other Youtube videos



On running this pipeline, I am not getting the folder unzipped properly


I expected all the files mentioned in the second screenshot will be there inside the 'ENCORE_Datafiles.zip' folder. But instead there is some binary file.
The catch here is, instead of having the zip folder which inturn have another folder, if I have the files directly inside the zip folder, the pipeline is able to unzip properly. But the zip file is something I am getting from a HTTP URL and I cannot do anything to modify the way I wanted. So, is there a way to unzip the zipped file which has a folder inturn inside it containing the files? Thanks in advance


So, is there a way to unzip the zipped file which has a folder inturn inside it containing the files?

The same pipeline design will give the expected results. This is my source zip file folder structure.

I have followed the same steps as yours and you can see it unzipped the inner files along with folders as well.

I tried with only files in the zip file as well, and it gave the expected results. To achieve your requirement, make sure you didn't give any Compression type for the sink binary dataset.

This my pipeline JSON for reference. Check whether all the configurations are same or not.
{
    "name": "Pipeline 1",
    "properties": {
        "activities": [
            {
                "name": "Copy data1",
                "type": "Copy",
                "dependsOn": [],
                "policy": {
                    "timeout": "0.12:00:00",
                    "retry": 0,
                    "retryIntervalInSeconds": 30,
                    "secureOutput": false,
                    "secureInput": false
                },
                "userProperties": [],
                "typeProperties": {
                    "source": {
                        "type": "BinarySource",
                        "storeSettings": {
                            "type": "AzureBlobFSReadSettings",
                            "recursive": true
                        },
                        "formatSettings": {
                            "type": "BinaryReadSettings",
                            "compressionProperties": {
                                "type": "ZipDeflateReadSettings"
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    "sink": {
                        "type": "BinarySink",
                        "storeSettings": {
                            "type": "AzureBlobFSWriteSettings",
                            "copyBehavior": "PreserveHierarchy"
                        }
                    },
                    "enableStaging": false
                },
                "inputs": [
                    {
                        "referenceName": "Binary1",
                        "type": "DatasetReference"
                    }
                ],
                "outputs": [
                    {
                        "referenceName": "Binary2",
                        "type": "DatasetReference"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ],
        "annotations": []
    }
}

